# Pandas: Convert DataFrame to Mean and Standard Deviation of Each Cell

Tags: python, csv, pandas, scikit-learn, dataframe

I have an unconventional DataFrame (which was read in from a csv). It looks like this:

```
SubjAns    a1      a2     demog
S1A1       "1,2,3" "4,6"      A
S1A2       "101,1" NaN        B
```

For each cell, I first need to convert the string to a list of floats (Is there a way for pandas to read it as a list of floats instead of a string?) and then I'd like to create a new DataFrame consisting of the mean and standard deviation:

```
SubjAns    a1_mean  a1_stdev a2_mean a2_stdev  demog
S1A1       3.0      1        5.0     1.41      A
S1A2       51.0     70.71    NaN     NaN       B
```

Is this possible? I'll ultimately be reading it into scikit-learn, so if any method is more optimal for that, please include that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way, is to write a mini parse-then-stat function

```
In [270]: df
Out[270]:
  SubjAns     a1   a2 demog
0    S1A1  1,2,3  4,6     A
1    S1A2  101,1  NaN     B
```

This, creates a float list, then numpy array and returns mean and std

```
In [271]: def split_stat(x):
   .....:     x = pd.np.array(list(map(float, str(x).split(','))))
   .....:     return x.mean(), x.std()
   .....:
```

You can then iterative over columns interested, in this case a1, a2 and then zip the results back to new columns.

```
In [272]: for col in ['a1', 'a2']:
   .....:     df[col+'_mean'], df[col+'_std'] = zip(*df[col].apply(split_stat))
   .....:
```

And, the output shall look like

```
In [273]: df
Out[273]:
  SubjAns     a1   a2 demog  a1_mean     a1_std  a2_mean  a2_std
0    S1A1  1,2,3  4,6     A        2   0.816497        5       1
1    S1A2  101,1  NaN     B       51  50.000000      NaN     NaN
```

Comment: The issue is that `x = pd.np.array(map(float, str(x).split(',')))` in `split_stat()` seems to be creating a map object, not a numpy array.

Comment: @Adam_G: In Python3, `map` returns a map object, not a list. So use `x = pd.np.array(list(map(float, str(x).split(','))))`.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thank you.